# Can't find solution to trigonometric equation, need help to understand why!

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

I am struggling with the solution of an equation and I think as well with a lack of understanding when there is a solution for such a trigonometric problem and when there will be infinitely many (speaking of 0 to pi only for x).

I am trying to solve the following equation:

$$(b - d) \cos(x) + (3 b + d) \cos(3 x) + a \sin(x) + c \sin(x) + 
       a \sin(3 x) - 3 c \sin(3 x) = 0$$

My assumptions are:
$(x, a, b, c, d) \in R ; \pi \geq x \geq 0$

I fed this into Mathematica and it runs for two days already, making me think that there is no sensible solution.

Can someone help me to understand if this is the case and why?
And maybe point me to something if there is any way to find at least some solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: Where does this equation come from?

Comment: I am trying to find maxima of this function:

Comment: $f(x)=cos^3(x) a - 3 cos^2(x)sin(x)c + 
  3 cos(x) sin^2(x) d + sin^3(x) b$;

So I took the derivative towards x and then set it to zero.

Comment: I don't understand if you look for $(\exists) a,b,c,d$ such that $(\forall) x$... the expression is (identically) zero, or is it find an $a$, a $b$..., a $x$ such that the expression is zero?

Comment: a,b,c,d are constants and I am searching for all x'es that make the equation become true, thus make expression equal to zero. So I want to solve towards x. Sorry for being a bit fuzzy in the above explanation.

Comment: So you want a solution (or solutions) in the parametric form $x=\phi(a,b,c,d)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express the functions of the triple angle as products of the functions of the angle (using the [triple-angle identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Triple-angle_formulae)), express the sine in terms of the cosine (using $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$), and solve the resulting algebraic equation for the cosine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! 
I will give it a try. 
I have a couple of questions regarding your answer:
1) So you are certain there are solutions, can you give me an intuition on how you know? Will this hold for even longer, similar expressions?
2) Is it possible to know how many solutions to expect?
3) Why doesn't Mathematica find a solution itself, shouldn't it "know" such identities?

Comment: @Wallie: 1) No, I'm not certain there are solutions. I'm certain that you'll find any possible solutions in this manner. 2) Yes, by looking at the degree of the resulting algebraic equation. It's of degree $3$ in the sine and cosine, and you need to square it once to get rid of the square root when you replace the sine, so it should end up being of degree $6$. So in the general case there'd be up to $6$ solutions for the cosine, yielding $12$ solutions for the angle modulo $2\pi$. 3) I don't know. Mathematica isn't omniscient. You can do some of the steps and see whether it can do the rest.

Comment: Thank you, that was very insightful. One last question before I'll try to solve it: How would my solution change if I restrict x to be within 0 and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ instead of 0 and $\pi$?

Comment: @Wallie: Sorry, I missed the "$0$ to $\pi$" part. In that case it's up to $6$, not $12$ solutions. If you restrict further to $[0,\frac\pi2]$, you'd only use the positive solutions for the cosine. How many there are would depend on the parameters -- and anyway it depends on the parameters how many real solutions there are, and how many of them lie between $[-1,1]$; general considerations only give you an upper bound how many solutions there might be. Also note that squaring may introduce spurious solutions, so you need to check that the solutions actually satisfy the unsquared equation.

Comment: Alright, your suggestion worked, thank you!